# Installing Jasny/Bootstrap with Composer for Symfony2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony, composer-php, jasny-bootstrap

Getting used to installing composer unaware packages for Symfony2 using Composer. The configuration for Twitter/Bootstrap was:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "twitter/bootstrap",
            "version": "2.3.0",
            "source": {
                "type": "git",
                "url": "https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap",
                "reference": "v2.3.0"
            }
        }
    }
 ],
```

but with Jasny/Bootstrap this

```
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "jasny/bootstrap",
            "version": "2.3.0-j4",
            "source": {
                "type": "git",
                "url": "https://github.com/jasny/bootstrap",
                "reference": "2.3.0-j4"
            }
        }
    }
```

fails with this

```
[UnexpectedValueException]                                                      
Could not parse version constraint 2.3.0-j4: Invalid version string "2.3.0-j4"
```

How to fix?  2.3.0-j4 is the latest version.  Is the"-j4" simply non-standard and breaking composer?

Unfortunately trying 2.3.* and >=2.3 as suggested results in similar errors.

```
[Composer\Repository\InvalidRepositoryException]
A repository of type "package" contains an invalid package definition: Undefined index: version

Invalid package definition:
{"name":"jasny\/bootstrap","version":"2.3.*","source":{"type":"git","url":"https:\/\/github.com\/jasny\/bootstrap","reference":"2.3.*"}}
```

Comment: The version your putting there is not valid: http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#version But don't ask me what to put instead, I dont know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version must follow the format of `X.Y.Z` with an optional suffix of `-dev`, `-alphaN`, `-betaN` or `-RCN`

from http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#version as mentioned by [cheesemacfly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1443490/cheesemacfly).

You can try `2.3.*` or `>=2.3` instead.

Comment: @Fo. And if you remove the version line from your file? From getcomposer.org: `Note: Packagist uses VCS repositories [...]. Specifying the version yourself will most likely end up creating problems at some point due to human error.`

Comment: dev-master works. So, I guess this means that I will never be able to rely on a stable release?

Comment: For now you can't. However this is already reported as an issue. https://github.com/jasny/bootstrap/issues/80

Comment: It turns out the developers of Jasny Bootstrap feel this is a bug with Composer and closed the ticket. Oh well!